# 'Workflow' to resubmit package to security review with corrections

Tags: security, appexchange

I had a technical question and wanted it to review it with you to make sure that I am following the right approach:

To submit the package for security review, I do the following steps:

1. I get the package from my developer. Let’s say the package is X.
2. I install the package in a dev org A.
3. I remove the package X. The code is still in dev org A.
4. I create a managed package Y with the namespace MyProduct
5. I release the managed package Y and submit it for security review.

This goes fine.

However, when it comes back from Security review, I need to modify the package. I cannot modify the package since it is already given for the security review. So, I use a different org, but then I cannot use the same namespace. What am I doing wrong

Comment: You make changes to code in Dev org , the org in point 1 and create a new version of the package and upload it. Follow the steps as @Eric has in his answer

Comment: Once you have uploaded the package, you will find the new version of the package visible in the publish console which you can submit for review. Give it few mins before you find the package in the publishing console

Answer (score 3):

If you need to modify the package, make the changes in the DE org where you created the package. Then upload a new package.

If you need to resubmit to Security Review, click the "Start Review" in the Publishing Console in your APO. You will not be changed again.

Then submit a case via the partner community letting them know that you have uploaded a new package and need to restart the review process.

You do NOT create a new org / namespace